# how to store data from html table in a view in mvc4

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a HTML table on a view in which user add some data at run time.I  want to save all rows of that table in database via controller .just like winform application where  for each loop is used for to save all rows.

Comment: Have a look at this post on model binding a list - http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view model for Your table:

```
public class YourTable
{
    public IEnumerable<YourRow> Rows { get; set; }
}
```

Create strongly typed view.

```
@model SomePath.YourTable

// Your table editable content
// form with submit value that will post viewmodel to controller action
```

And in controller action You should process the post:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveTable(YourTable yourTable)
{
    // save your table to the database
}
```